# What's the name of this connector?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, cables, connectors

I have a ceiling light fixture with four bulbs and a fan. A while back, two of the bulbs stopped working, but the bulbs themselves were not broken, as putting them into another lamp showed the bulbs were working fine.

Today I finally decided to open the fixture and see if this is something I can fix.

I opened the box, and even though I don't understand the circuit, I noticed that one of the cables was pinched (is this the right term?) like so:

[image: pinched cable]

I think it is likely the cable is broken inside, so it would be a good idea to replace the connection and see if this fixes the problem.

As you can see in the picture, the cable is attached to the male part of a connector, while the female part leads to another cable.

I wasn't able to open the connector, so I might need to buy a new one. Does anybody know the name of this connector so I can find it in my local electronic shop?

Here's a front view of the connector in question.

[image: Connector]

Comment: Have you tested that wire with a meter to see if you actually have a problem? If it is still good then all you need to do is just re-route the cable so it is no longer pinched.

Comment: The other end of the cable ends inside a resin block, so I can't really test it...

Comment: Well, there are ways to deal with that : use a pin...

Answer (score 3):

Looks a little like a bullet connector / terminal.

[image]

If you have access to the other end of the connector that you think is broken, you could disconnect it & test the wire to see if it's really broken using a multimeter (set to ohms / resistance), or test it in place with the power off. Maybe that wire's not the problem, there are a lot of other electronics in there too.

Most light fixtures just use cheap wire nuts to twist two wires together, you could just cut & strip both ends of the wire and use a wire nut.

PS Don't forget to check why it was pinched & don't do it again.

Comment: You should mention, as per my comment, to re-route the cable so it is no longer pinched...